# Can my bike do enduro/AM racing?

Tags: mountain-bike

I would like to ask if my bike is able to do enduro/AM racing.

[image: Giant Stance 27.5]

Specs:

```
Giant Stance 27.5 2
Deore 2014 RD 10spd (with switch)
Deore 2014 shifters 
Deore 2014 brake set
FSA Comet 24/30/40 crank set (stock parts, already hollow tech)
Alivio 2015 FD Highband
Rockshox gold tk 30 solo air 2015 fork 120mm travel (with rebound adjuster and lockout)
Rockshox Monarch R rear suspension 120mm travel (rebound only)
2014 ZTR Crest rims
origin 8 hubs
pillars spokes
Schawlbe nobby nic evo tires
Tubeless setup (stans sealant)
Deore 10 spd sprocket
Deore chain 10 spd(not sure if deore or just shimano non series)
Giant Cockpit(HB - 720mm, stem - 90mm +-6 degree, stock giant seatpost)
```

If I need to upgrade any parts then I'm open to suggestions, opinions and flames.

Comment: Do you have a particular race in mind? What's the terrain like? What is the distance?

Comment: here is the trails, its one of the few trails that's very near to me.
http://www.bisikleta.ph/2013/05/biking-in-manila-heroes-trail.html

some trails are a 6 hours ride from my place.

@JamesG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that bike is more than adequate for that type of riding.  The only thing you *might* consider tailoring for your riding styles would be the tires.  The trail you posted looks pretty smooth.  If you got into some trails that were looser or rocky then you could go with something more knobby and/or higher volume.

I say just ride the bike and enjoy the trails.  If you haven't already, figure out how to dial in your suspension and you should get tons of great riding out of that bike.

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful reply. That gave me more confidence on riding my bike on these trails...